# Battleship game in python ship placement issues

Tags: python

I am creating a battleship game with a board that is 10x10, looking as such:

```
-------------------------------------------------
 0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 |
-------------------------------------------------
10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
-------------------------------------------------
20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |
-------------------------------------------------
30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 |
-------------------------------------------------
40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 |
-------------------------------------------------
50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 |
-------------------------------------------------
60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 |
-------------------------------------------------
70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 |
-------------------------------------------------
80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 |
-------------------------------------------------
90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have been able to print this with my code but now I'm trying to write a function that checks if the choice is a position where a ship can be placed within the board.

This is a hint that I have been given, but I literally cannot figure out how to solve this.

If choice is 88, shipDir is horizontal and shipType is 3, then ship does not fit as it will take positions 88-89-90 and 90 is a position in the next line (and so ship will be out of the board).

If choice is 88, shipDir is vertical and shipType is 3, then also ship does not fit as it will take positions 88-98-108 and 108 is out of the board.

This function also checks if the chosen position is a position that is already taken by another ship on the board.

Function should return `False` if a ship is out of the board and if a ship position is taken another ship on the board. Function should return `True` otherwise.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I sense some "what have you tried?" in the air

Comment: to be completely honest i do not know where to begin

Comment: this is extra credit for my introduction to programming class. I am mainly doing it for fun and to try and learn some more python

Comment: What you probably need to do is think about a better data structure. One possibility is a 12 by 12 array array or a twelve element list of twelve element lists. That way you could have an "edge" to your array of "illegal" positions that would be easy to detect.

I'm not saying that this is the best way to solve the problem just that thinking of a data structure first is a good way to approach a programming problem.

Comment: It's remarkably tough to help without actually knowing what your internals look like.

Comment: Starting with a smaller board, say 3x3 with ships 2 units long might be easier to figure out. Also, using the coordinates of the spaces rather than your numbering scheme would help.

Answer (score 3):

The comments in your post hint at what you should be doing. For example, James Thiele suggests making an index of good and bad locations for edge effects. I like this idea. An incredibly powerful way to do this is to leverage the power of `numpy`'s broadcasting to do the checking for you. The advantage with a method like this is the ability to define "non-traditional" ships, say ships that are not simply linear in shape.

I'm going to post a full solution below for pedagogic reasons, that is, I'd like it to be useful for you to learn from. Being homework, please code the solution yourself - but take what you can from the answer below. You'll notice that I define a "non-traditional" U-shaped ship as an example.

```
import numpy as np

# Define the problem
N  = 10
msl = 4 # max_ship_length

# Reserve the boards
BOARD = np.zeros((N,N))
CHECK = np.zeros((N+msl,N+msl))

# Mark the positions outside the board as bad
CHECK[:N,:N] = 1

# Define some ships
battleship  = np.array([[0,1,2,3],[0,0,0,0]])
patrol = np.array([[0,1],[0,0]])
uboat  = np.array([[0,0,1,2,2],[1,0,0,0,1]])
v_idx = [1,0]

def try_place(location, ship, color):
    location = np.reshape(location,(2,1))
    idx = zip(location+ship)
    if CHECK[idx].all() and not BOARD[idx].any():
        BOARD[idx] = color
        return True
    return False

def random_spot(): return np.random.random_integers(0,N-1,2)

# Check some random locations for ships and place them if possible
for _ in xrange(3):
    try_place(random_spot(), patrol, 1)             # Horz. patrol boat
    try_place(random_spot(), battleship, 2)         # Horz. battleship
    try_place(random_spot(), battleship[v_idx], 2)  # Vertical battleship
    try_place(random_spot(), uboat, 3)              # Horz. UBoat
```

You can visualize the board created with `pylab`

```
import pylab as plt
plt.matshow(BOARD)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should post how you are representing the data internally, not just what you print out.

However, from your output, I imagine you have a linear list, and use some kind of element in there to know wether it does "contain a ship" or "not contain a ship".

The advise is to forget about it, and take the oprtunity to learn more about Object Oriented coding - so that you can have a "Board" class that will know about its contents, and a "`can_place_ship(self, <coord>, <shipsize>, <shiporientation>)` " method, for example.

Here, try this tutorial for the OO part:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml (just picked a link from google's first results)